# Why doesn't my chain method attempt in Java work?

Tags: java, android

In Udacity's beginner's course for developing an android app, they introduce a brief example of chaining method in one of their beginner's lessons.

Here's the snippet of the code:

```
public void submitOrder(View view) {

    /** 
     * Chaining method example given by Udacity. 
     * stringName variable successfully receives the string value.
     */
    EditText inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_input);
    String stringName = inputName.getText().toString(); 

    /** 
     * My own example. 
     * Cannot resolve method 'toString()' error message occurs.
     */
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check_box);
    String hasWhippedCream = checkBox.isChecked().toString();

    // What I found by searching on google to make 'toString' work on Boolean
    String has = Boolean.toString(checkBox.isChecked());

}
```

What the instructor on Udacity says is that, in order for a chaining method to work, the first return value must contain the following method in its class.

As for the above example, she explained that `inputName.getText()` returns `Editable` object & it has `toString()` method within its class, thus this chaining method is valid and will return string upon `toString()` call on it and gets saved in stringName.

My confusion arises when I try to implement the same format of chaining method on `Boolean` return. In my own example above, I call `checkBox.isChecked()`, which has return type `boolean`. Now, `Boolean` does have `toString()` method according to android documentation, so it should work, but it does not with error message popping up.

However, the format I found on google does work:

```
String has = Boolean.toString(checkBox.isChecked())
```

Question:

- Why is that my chaining method on boolean return type won't work?
- Is there a set of rules for which format to follow when creating a chaining method as shown above? Why does `Boolean` have a different format of chaining method from `inputName.getText()` as shown above?

Comment: `Boolean` is an `Object`.. `boolean` on the other hand is a primitive and doesn´t have methods

Comment: @KevinEsche You may as well submit that as the answer, rather than as a comment, since that's the issue here

Comment: @Kevin Esche Thank you so much Kevin for directing me to right question. I'm really a newbie, can't even do the search right :(. Thank you so much though! :)

Comment: `Boolean.valueOf(checkBox.isChecked()).toString() ` is probably what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Boolean` and `boolean` is a different type in Java (notice the B).
`Boolean` is a wrapper class, it provides the mechanism to convert primitive data type (`boolean` in this case) into object and object into primitive.

This works: `Boolean.toString(checkBox.isChecked());`
because it uses the Boolean wrapper class' static method `toString` to convert a **primitive boolean returned by** `isChecked()` method from `checkBox` **to a `Boolean` object**.

More info about wrapper class:

1. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html
2. http://www.javatpoint.com/wrapper-class-in-java

simply said, `isChecked()` returns a primitive `boolean`, which doesn't have any method, so you cannot do method chaining there.